# Use numpy.loadtxt() to load txt file with tab delimiter FAIL

Tags: python, numpy, delimiter

I am trying to use numpy.loadtxt() to load .txt file of tab delimiter. But I ran a erro that it reads come information together with tab, e.g. ' 1 2 3', which can not be converted into float data.

data = np.loadtxt("myfile.txt", delimiter='\t')

---

it looks like the file has delimiter of '\n'. Another question is, how to tell which delimiter is, of '\t' and '\n', in the txt file before printing it out?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?  Evidently at least one row has a column with '1 2 3' that aren't separated by a tab.  The default load format is float.  Reread the `loadtxt` docs if necessary.  And consider providing a sample of the file if you need more help.

Comment: I just figured that the delimiter is '\n', not '\t'. Do you know how to tell the difference in the txt file without printing it?

Answer (score 0):

The default for delimiter is **any whitespace**.
And if there is `\n` then numpy has the next row like below code.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> dataset = StringIO('''\
... 4\t5\n6 7\n8\t\t\t\t\t\t9''')
>>> dataset_as_numpy = numpy.loadtxt(dataset)
>>> dataset_as_numpy
array([[ 4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9.]])
```

Actually, we can tell the difference in the text file without printing it or opening it. It's important to figure out the format of the dataset before doing some task.

Comment: Yeah, I know \n means the next line, but just wondering how can we tell the difference if we just open the text file, because in my case, the text file only show whitespace between numbers, but it turns out that the one whitespace is actually \n.

Comment: @Hao Xu, I think that the alternative way is to use 'show whitespaces' in your text editor. Or another way is to rewrite the data after loading data to string format using `open()` . Sorry for that awkward reply.

Comment: that is totally fine. Don't worry. I think the best way is to print out the file after reading it, then I can see \t or \n included in the print. Thanks!